# TypeError: OpenAIApi is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

i got error:

```
const openai = new OpenAIApi({ key: apiKey });
               ^

TypeError: OpenAIApi is not a constructor
```

when I'm trying to create an openai api using nodejs (v16.7.0). I've followed the code in documentation and installed the openai api (v4.3.1)

code I used:

```
const { OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAIApi({ key: apiKey });
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: maybe try doing `npm install openai` again just incase and check to see if the versions are compatible after `npm show openai version`

Answer (score 4):

Accordingly to [documentation](https://github.com/openai/openai-node#request--response-types) you don't have to use destructure operator on imported object.

If you ommit it, everything should run fine.

```js
const OpenAIApi = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAIApi({ key: apiKey });
```

UPD. Actually required object contains needed class, it's `OpenAI`.
So you have to specify the correct name:

```js
const { OpenAI } = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAI({ key: apiKey });
```

UPD2. As [Mr. Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762224/mr-polywhirl) mentioned in comments, there exists third approach. It's to use class that lies inside imported library object.

```js
const OpenAIApi = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAIApi.OpenAI({ key: apiKey });
```

Comment: By "spread", I think you mean "destructure". This is because the `openai` library has a default export.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yeah, take this as a typo :D

Comment: Alternatively, you can still import the whole library (not advised) and call `new OpenAIApi.OpenAI({ key: process.env.API_KEY })` Assuming you should also use `dotenv` for environment variables. **Update:** You still would not destructure. You can name the default export anything you want when you import.

Comment: I've apply it to the code but it got error

```Error: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide i t, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apikey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'my apikey' })```

Comment: @JustineGwapo that is just an example of using `dotenv`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl added your option to the answer, ty

Comment: @JustineGwapo it's next step you should do. There should be pasted an actual API key from your [OpenAI](https://openai.com/) account

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that you used version 3 code, but probably have installed the newest version (like myself), which is 4.
Check the latest docs, they changed a lot of stuff: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai/v/4.12.4

Answer (score 1):

All should need to do is remove the curly braces (destructuring).

```js
const OpenAIApi = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAIApi({ key: apiKey });
```

Note that the [official documentation](https://github.com/openai/openai-node#request--response-types) advises you name the import `OpenAI` per the example usage, but you should be able to name it anything you like.

If you open up `node_modules/openai/src/index.js`, you will see `exports.default = OpenAI;` as the bottom. This is exporting `class OpenAI extends Core.APIClient` as the default export. This means you can name it anything you want, when you import the library.

```js
const FooBar = require('openai');

const openai = new FooBar({ key: apiKey });
```

What may seem confusing is that `index.ts` has the following exports. The class and the namespace have the same name.

```
export class OpenAI extends Core.APIClient {
  // ...
}

export namespace OpenAI {
  // Helper functions
  export import toFile = Uploads.toFile;
  // ...
}

export default OpenAI; // Add namespace functions as static methods to the class
```

This compiles to the following JS, because `esModuleInterop` is set to `true` in the `openai-node` libraries [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/master/tsconfig.json)

```js
exports.OpenAI = OpenAI;
exports.toFile = Uploads.toFile;
(function (OpenAI) {
  // Helper functions
  OpenAI.toFile = Uploads.toFile;
  // ...
})((OpenAI = exports.OpenAI || (exports.OpenAI = {})));
exports = module.exports = OpenAI;
exports.default = OpenAI;
```

---

### A better approach

Store your API key appropriately

1. Install [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) as a dependency

```bash
npm install dotenv
```

2. Add an `API_KEY` to your `.env` file at the root of your project

```bash
echo "API_KEY=" >> .env
```

3. Update the server script

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const OpenAI = require('openai');

dotenv.config() // Load the environment

const openai = new OpenAI({ key: process.env.API_KEY });
```

### Alternatively

You can use the preferred environment variable

```bash
echo "OPENAI_API_KEY=" >> .env
```

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const OpenAI = require('openai');

dotenv.config() // Load the environment

const openai = new OpenAI(); // The key is picked-up automagically
```

Comment: ```const apiKey = process.env['apiKey']; ``` this is in my code and the value is right

Comment: @JustineGwapo so what's your current issue then?

Answer (score 1):

You must update your package.json to specify v4:

```
 "openai": "^4.0.0"
```

Run "npm install".

After this, you can use:

```
const OpenAI = require("openai");
const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

More info: https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217